# SwiftUI Storing field entry as a double or integer

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to store a user's text field entry as a number so it's easier to work with in formulas. I thought I was being slick by storing it as a string, but now using the input in mathematical formulas is becoming a real pain in the neck. It should be noted that these field entries are being stored in CoreData currently as a string entity.

Here's an MRE of one of my fields:

```
import SwiftUI

struct EntryMRE: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @State private var showingResults: Int? = 1
    
    @FocusState private var isTextFieldFocused: Bool
    @State var isDone = false
    
    @State var isSaving = false //used to periodically save data
    @State var saveInterval: Int = 5 //after how many seconds the data is automatically saved

    //DataPoints Chemistry
    @State var potassium = ""
  
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text(" Chemistry")) {
                Group {
                    HStack {
                        Text("K")
                        + Text("+")
                            .font(.system(size: 15.0))
                            .baselineOffset(4.0)
                        Spacer()
                        TextField("mEq/L", text: $potassium)
                            .focused($isTextFieldFocused)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
                            .modifier(TextFieldClearButton(text: $potassium))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                        if let numberValue = Double(potassium) { // Cast String to Double
                            if (3.5...5.5) ~= numberValue {
                                Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGreen))
                            }
                            else {
                                Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.circle.fill")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemRed))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While not specifically using the $potassium value, here is what I'm currently having to do for formulas:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ResultView: View {
    @Binding var isDone: Bool
    var EV: EntryView
    
    let decimalPlaces: Int = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Formula")) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Corrected CO2")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(1.5 * (Double(EV.hCo3) ?? 0) + 8, specifier: "%.\(decimalPlaces)f")")
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your `@State var potassium` to be of type `Double` you can use a different initializer for your `TextField`.

```
@State var potassium = 0.0

TextField("mEq/L", value: $potassium, format: .number)
```

Of course you would need to change your `CoreData` model to to be of type `Double` but I think this should have been a `Double` in the first place.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Something weird is happening and causing the app to crash. I've changed the string type in CoreData as well as the onAppear and in the func. This is going to require some futsing.

Comment: @BFBone whats the error message?

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140 "Persistent store migration failed, missing mapping model."

Comment: @BFBone you should delete the app from the device your are testing after changing the model. It seems there is still old `CoreData` on the device.